# Utility method in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to create a utility method in Vue.js to validate a decimal number from **any** input field but I'm not sure how to set the value in Vue.js internally.

This is what I did in jQuery before:

```
$('body').on('blur', '.decimal', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if ($.isNumeric(val)) {
        val = parseFloat(val).toFixed(2);
        $(this).val(val);
    } else {
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
```

This is what I have in Vue but the value is not stored internally and is overwritten.

```
function isNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

```
methods: {
    validateDecimal: function (e) {
        var val = e.target.value;

        if (isNumeric(val)) {
            e.target.value = parseFloat(val).toFixed(2);
        } else {
            e.target.value = '';
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<input class="ui-input" :value="some.value" placeholder="0.00" @blur="validateDecimal">
<input class="ui-input" :value="some.othervalue" placeholder="0.00" @blur="validateDecimal">
<input class="ui-input" :value="another.dynamic.input" placeholder="0.00" @blur="validateDecimal">
```

Comment: How are the values overwritten?

Comment: They are set until another element on the page is changed. Then the value reverts to what was entered.

Comment: Would you not just call `validateDecimal(myValueToValidate)` whenever you require it? Then parse that to your data object? Which you can use a [setter](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) or `v-model` on an input.

Comment: @swonder, could you post an example, I consider myself a Vue newbie. I am not using v-model because the inputs can be added dynamically.

Comment: (just saw your edit), so they're dynamic. Have you tried `:value="validateDecimal(some.value)"`?

Comment: I'll give that a try but I'm assuming it would update the value as it's typed? I wanted it to validate on blur

Comment: That's exactly what I would think would happen as well.

Comment: How do you dynamically create your inputs? Could you give them names?

Comment: I can but I wanted to create a method that I can use on `any` input if that is possible? They are created in a `v-for`

Comment: I ask because you can make use of [$refs](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) then pass the ref to the function, get the value, validate it then re-set it to it's new value.

Comment: I love refs but I also feel like I'm drawing a squiggly line from one thing to another.

Comment: Is it possible to validate it in `computed` rather then `methods` and return the validated value?

Comment: A computed property will only return a single value, method is what you need. I'm just really stretching my brain here. As a guy who uses vue.js on a daily basis, this one is really racking my brain.

Comment: I would add more detail to my code but it's getting quite a large page with ajax calls etc. so it would take a bit of separating out to create a demo. I thought it might be common question/issue

Comment: I don't see a way you could create dynamic inputs without using $refs to go back and re-set the value once it's changed through the event.

Comment: I can give it a go. I've not used them before yet.

Comment: I'm looking at $refs but don't you need to know the name of the element?

Comment: Yeah but you can bind the ref when you create the element using your v-for, couldn't you? The ref could even be a generated uuid.

Comment: yeh, but how would the general purpose utility method know the name of the ref to use?

Comment: The ref could be assigned to a prop on the target input, so then you could just do `this.$refs[e.target.getAttribute("type")]`... (I'm not sure if this is what swonder was thinking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can pass the data object reference to the handler method like so:
(Note you can't just pass the data property, because I don't believe it will be a reference.)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    inputs:{
      'v1':{
        value:'1.256'
      },
      'v2':{
        value:'1.521'
      }
    },
    someInput:{value:'1.7125'}
  },
  methods:{
    validateDecimal: function (o,p,e) {
        console.log('validateDecimal',o);
        var val = e.target.value;
        console.log(val);
        if (Number(parseFloat(val)) == val) {
            val = parseFloat(val).toFixed(2);
            this.$set(o, p, val);
        } else {
            this.$set(o, p, '');
            e.target.value = '';
        }
    },
    foo: function(){
      console.log(this.inputs.v1.value)
      console.log(this.inputs.v2.value)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="i,key in this.inputs">
    <input class="ui-input" :value="i.value" placeholder="0.00" @blur="validateDecimal(i, 'value', $event)">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="ui-input" :value="this.someInput.value" placeholder="0.00" @blur="validateDecimal(someInput,'value', $event)">
  </div>
  <button @click="foo">Click</button>
</div>
```

Edit by OP: Adding an extra parameter for the name of the property and using `$set` to make the dynamic property reactive. This should make the method more general purpose for any dynamic input fields with any property name.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code as to why/how it helps solve OP's issue.

Comment: Not tried it yet, but how would this line work with any input field? `var val = this.some[name]` when `some` is explicitly used?

Comment: For the record, I didn't downvote. I thought it was a good effort

Comment: I tried wrapping the code with `this.$nextTick(() => {});` and it made no difference

Comment: Did you use  `this.some[name] = ~~~` ? I think the use of this.$nextTick is so that we wait for vue to update the model after the blur event, and then process our change. Otherwise you would need to use the target value, which you can do by using the event in the parameters. I think you would do `@blur="validateDecimal('value',$event)"`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Your right, passing the value as the first parameter and then updating that value in the method seems to keep it synced internally.
`@blur="validateDecimal('value',$event)"`

Comment: Wait, although this works, you still need to know the name of the property in the method. E.g. you couldn't make it a general purpose method by using `k.price` and `k.sale_price`. It doesn't seem to work by passing in the property alone like `validateDecimal(i.sale_price,$event)`.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's because of how javascript passes references. If you pass the prop alone then you just get the value or something, yea? So if you just pass the prop (which calls get() and gets just the value)--- when you go to set the value... well you're not setting the vue value, you're just changing the local variable.

Comment: I've just done a bit of digging and I've figured it out. I'll just modify your answer.

Comment: After going through all this, I imagine something like `<input class="ui-input" :value="i.value" placeholder="0.00" @blur="i.value = validateDecimal($event)">` is more canonical.

Comment: Which also means that `<input class="ui-input" :value="this.someInput" placeholder="0.00" @blur="someInput = validateDecimal($event)">` works as well.